# what does ?body=1 do in rails 3.1 asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In development, all my javascript assets are being appended with the `body=1` get variable.  What is this actually doing?

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Trawling through the Sprocket source code we find:

```
  # Returns a 200 OK response tuple
  def ok_response(asset, env)
    if body_only?(env)
      [ 200, headers(env, asset, Rack::Utils.bytesize(asset.body)), [asset.body] ]
    else
      [ 200, headers(env, asset, asset.length), asset ]
    end
  end
```

`body_only?` is set when `?body=1 or true`

For a static asset, `Asset.body` is defined as:

```
def body
  # File is read everytime to avoid memory bloat of large binary files
  pathname.open('rb') { |f| f.read }
end
```

Whereas passing the asset back its self is a "Rack-capable body object"

```
# Add enumerator to allow `Asset` instances to be used as Rack
# compatible body objects.
def each
  yield to_s
end
```

When we look at the `bundled_asset`, the `Asset.body` is redefined as retrieving the body of the asset only and not including any dependencies. `Asset.to_a` is defined as retrieving the asset its self as well as all of its dependencies as an array passed on to Rack.

In this way, assets aren't combined together but taken as individual objects, so individual CSS files are still individual.